# a++-++a в Java пост и пред инкременты

Tags: java, инкремент

Сломать мозг можно... Почему результат -2 ?

```
int a = 0;
System.out.println(a++-++a);
```

Сломать, потому что даже если а = любому другому значению, результат всегда -2.

Кто-то может объяснить ?

П.с. Объяснить для человека, который только недавно понял почему сравнивая Integer 127 получаем значения true, а 128 false

Comment: Какой результат ожидается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результат именно таков, потому что в Java приоритет операций постфиксного/префиксного инкремента `x++/++x` приоритет выше, чем операция вычитания; вычисления сложных выражений вычисляются в порядке слева направо:

- `a++ - ++a`

1. `a++` - результатом операции остается 0, в `a` становится 1
2. `++a` - результатом операции остается 2, в `a` становится 2
3. `0 - 2 = -2`

---

- `++a - a++`

1. `++a` - результатом операции остается 1, в `a` становится 1
2. `a++` - результатом операции остается 1, в `a` становится 2
3. `1 - 1 = 0`

---

- `++a - ++a`

1. `++a` - результатом операции остается 1, в `a` становится 1
2. `++a` - результатом операции остается 2, в `a` становится 2
3. `1 - 2 = -1`

---

- `a++ - a++`

1. `a++` - результатом операции остается 0, в `a` становится 1
2. `a++` - результатом операции остается 1, в `a` становится 2
3. `0 - 1 = -1`

Answer (score 0):

```
a++ - ++a
^----------- x
 ^^--------- a = x+1
^^^--------- x
        ^--- x+1
      ^^---- a = x+2
      ^^^--- x+2
    ^------- x - (x+2)
             -2
```

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

Comment: @RomanC, и почему же не содержит?